# Hefsek between Karpas and maror?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, hefsek-interruption, marror-bitter-herbs

In Shulchan Aruch (O”Ch 475:1):

> ויברך על אכילת מרור ויאכלנו בלא הסיבה ואח"כ נוטל מצה שלישית ובוצע ממנה וכורכה עם המרור וטובלה בחרוסת: הגה ויש אומרים דאין לטובלו וכן הוא במנהגים וכן ראיתי נוהגין: ואומר זכר למקדש כהלל ואוכלם ביחד בהסיב'- “And he should bless ‘... to eat the bitter herbs’ and he should eat it [the maror] without leaning, and then he should take the third matza, and break it, and make a sandwich with maror ... and says ‘as a memory of the temple according to Hillel.’”

Biur Halacha on this paragraph:

> ואומר זכר למקדש - קשה הלא אמירה זו הוי הפסק בין ברכה לכריכה ...וצ״ע- “and he says ‘as a memory of the temple according to hillel’- this is hard [to understand], because saying this [after the b’racha, before the first bite] is a hefsek between the b’racha and the sandwich... and it [this problem] needs looking in to”

So if according to the biur Halacha, speaking between hamotzi and eating Korech is considered a hefsek (hamotzi counts for Korech, and there’s no b’racha on Korech), why isn’t speaking between Karpas and maror also considered a hefsek? (We know it isn’t a hefsek because we say the Haggadah in between, the question is ‘why not?’)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not making a hefsek between המוציא and eating korech, because there isn't a problem to speak after the beracha rishona once you have already eaten. The Shulchan Aruch says not to make a hefsek between על אכילת מצה and על אכילת מרור and eating korech because they are blessings on the commandment of eating matsa and maror, and according to Hilel's opinion you haven't yet performed the mitsva until you ate the korech, and therefore there is the problem of hefsek according to his view.

> ומשבירך על אכילת מצה לא יסיח בדבר שאינו מענין הסעודה עד שיאכל כריכה זו כדי שתעלה **ברכת אכילת מצה וברכת אכילת מרור** גם לכריכה זו

But there's no problem with not eating the maror immediately after saying בורא פרי האדמה because you eat the karpas immediately after the blessing, so there's no hefsek between the blessing and the eating.

Comment: @b a                                                                         We specifically don’t eat a kezayis of Karpas so we don’t have to say a b’racha achrona, so that we don’t have to say a b’racha rishona on the maror, but ideally you shouldn’t have a hefsek between starting to eat and finishing a kezayis (for example not talking after hamotzi until you finish a kezayis), so there is still an inyan of hefsek and the question still stands

Comment: @Loani Where does not having a hefsek until eating an olive's amount come from? The reason for a beracha rishona is אסור לו לאדם שיהנה מן העולם הזה בלא ברכה ([Berachot 35a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=35&format=pdf)). Nothing to do with how much you eat